# How to load django installed apps staticfiles in production on Heroku?

Tags: django, heroku

This is probably a really simple adjustment that I've lost enough time searching for a solution. I built a project using Django + React and deployed it on Heroku. Everything works perfectly excepts for the static files from the `INSTALLED_APPS`: /admin and de Django Rest Framework views. In these urls, django throws a 500 server error.

`django.contrib.staticfiles` is in my `INSTALLED_APPS`. I'm using whitenoise. My allowed hosts are correct. My `STATIC_ROOT` path is also correct.

```
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(FRONTEND_DIR, "build", "static")
```

I've tried to add an empty directory in the `STATICFILES_DIRS` but it didn't work.

When I visit /admin/, the following error appears:

```
ValueError: Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'admin/css/base.css'
```

And when I visit /api/v1/:

```
ValueError: Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'rest_framework/css/bootstrap.min.css'
```

If I remove the line `STATICFILES_STORAGE = "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage"`, I can reach the routes above. However, these pages seems to be missing some `CSS`.

What am I missing? Why django isn't collecting the static files from the `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: run the command `python manage.py collectstatic`. This will create a folder staticfiles (if debug=false). Also you may have to change `STATIC_URL = "/staticfiles/"`

Comment: @ViLuWi I had already done that and was unsuccessfully. Actually, I need to create the folder before running the command. Otherwise it'll throw an `FileNotFoundError`.

Comment: What are the details of the 500 error mentioned?  What is the error message?  What is the traceback?

Comment: @RyanNowakowski It's basically what I've described: django didn't collect the installed apps static files. I just updated the question.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you to follow [Heroku's Django Guideline for static files](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets#whitenoise)

It is really helpful, and easy to follow.

Comment: I've followed this already and it didn't work. And btw if you follow this to deploy django + react it won't work. It applies much more when you create your templates with django.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#managing-static-files-e-g-images-javascript-css), you could have a problem by deploying it on Heroku :

> During development, if you use django.contrib.staticfiles, this will
> be done automatically by runserver when DEBUG is set to True (see
> django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve()).
>
> This method is grossly inefficient and probably insecure, so it is
> unsuitable for production.

I imagine you have DEBUG set to False on Heroku ?

If you implememnt the solution given by the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/deployment/#serving-static-files-in-production), do you still have this problem ?

I tried with the package [django-storage](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/gcloud.html) and gcloud and it worked perfectly for me. I added `django.contrib.staticfiles` in INSTALLED_APPS and configure `STATICFILES_STORAGE` and `STATIC_URL`.

It may add some work but at least you will have a clean installation on Heroku, suitable for production.

Comment: Yes, `DEBUG` is set to `False`. I still have this problem if I implement like the the docs. And yes I could store these files outside heroku but it's not the solution I'm looking to. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install django-heroku
```

Put this in your settings:

```
import django_heroku

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Comment: Remeber I'm using react, this won't even load my static files.